# Vimeo API firing multiple events on end

Tags: javascript, vimeo, vimeo-api

I'm using the [Vimeo API](https://developer.vimeo.com/player/sdk/reference), and the documentation states, to catch the end of a video use the following code

```
player.on('ended', function(data) {
  // `data` is an object containing properties specific to that event
});
```

Which works great, but when the video has ended, the vimeo video player stops the video (obviously), but places the progress back to 0.00.

Because of this, the `pause` and `seeked` events are also fired, meaning when a video ends, the events triggered look like this

[image]

It makes sense why it's triggering the `pause` and `seeked` events also, but it is far from ideal. I'm wanting to send an ajax request to save the progress, meaning if I listen for the `ended` event, it's going to fire 3 times.

Has anyone come across this before and figured a way around it?

Comment: Also running into this. Not very ideal at all and almost no way to tell them apart.

Comment: @user1842315 will post an answer with my work around

Comment: I´m also having this problem. The vimeo js sdk git repo already has a bug issue report for this issue? Anyone knows?

Comment: @AdrielWerlich Don't think there is a solution just yet, check out my own answer at the bottom for a workaround I used, that is still working currently!

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to fix this directly with the API as far as i'm aware, my method of getting around this was to watch the progress, check when the video was nearly finished and removed the bindings and set the progress as complete.

```
videoPlayer.on('progress', (data) => {
//If the player percent is over 0.95, updateProgress to 100% and remove all listeners
    if(data.percent > 0.95){
        //Manually set the data to 100
        data.percent = 1;
        //Remove the listeners
        videoPlayer.off('pause');
        videoPlayer.off('seeked');
        videoPlayer.off('progress');
        //Update the progress to be 100
        updateProgress(data, 'seeked');
    }
})
```

This turned out to be a better work around for my scenario anyway, as our videos have credits on the end, and the users ended up clicking off the video during the credits meaning the video was never technically marked as complete.

Comment: I had a similar issue and ended up using the `timeupdate` event instead, as the `progress` data seems to refer to the amount of the video that has loaded/buffered, and not the amount that has elapsed.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when I was using the API to trigger GA events in Tag Manager. It was generating two additional `pause` events each side of the `ended` event. In the end I had to inspect the event label and `percent` value, and if they equalled `pause` and `1` respectively I ignored that event. Worked well. Perhaps something similar could be done for `seeked` event, checking for `percent` equalling `0` and following the `pause` at `1` event?